# При запуске тестов из консоли запускается только один класс с тестами

Tags: java, maven, junit

Проект maven имеет следующую структуру:

[image: Структура проекта]

При запуске из консоли команды "mvn clean test" прогоняется только класс simpleTest, ломается на одном тесте и заканчивает работу, а simpleTestAllured тоже содержащий тесты игнорируется. Как сделать так, чтобы прогонялись все тестовые классы?

pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>qa_InSAT</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaTestingTools</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ru.yandex.qatools.ashot/ashot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.ashot</groupId>
            <artifactId>ashot</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>io.qameta.allure.junit4.AllureJunit4</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/cwacPqUEyic - лог

Comment: Все тестовые классы должны заканчиватся на Test

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @Chubatiy не обязательно.

Answer (score 0):

Обновите `maven-surefire-plugin` до более новой версии, например последней сейчас 2.22.1